# SQL query does not return any data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I'm trying to test a query used in a stored procedure.

That stored procedure is copied from another database where it is used to work.

Stored procedure will accept one parameter `yyyymm`, for example `202006`

It has a query that uses `substrings` from that parameter for month and year.

That's how month and year data is calculated:

```
declare @themonth nvarchar(15) = '202006'

declare @month nvarchar(5)
set @month = substring(@themonth,5,2)

declare @year nvarchar(5)
set @year= substring(@themonth,1,4)
```

When selecting data for `202006`, I'm getting all the records for that parameter.

So, here is some parts of the logic. I do not nee to write the whole query here.
I will just provide some pseudo code:

```
Select top 10000 mmi.theMonth, *
from (here we have inner joins)

where mmi.theMonth = @theMonth
```

When executing that, I'm getting:

```
theMonth   rptdate
202006     2020-06-30 00:00:00.000
```

rptdate is of date datatype
themonth is nvarchar(6)

Now when adding another condition to that query, nothing is returned.

Here is a condition:

```
and rptdate like @month + '%' and rptdate like '%' + @year
```

I'm not sure why. `2020-06-30 00:00:00.000` contains `@month = '06' and @year = '2020'`

What is wrong with that logic?

Comment: `@month + '%'` will match strings BEGINNING with the month.  `'%' + @year` will match strings ENDING with the year.

Comment: `rptdate` is a `date`. Using a `LIKE` against it makes no sense. A `date` isn't `LIKE` a `varchar`. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1):

You had the wildcard character `%` in the wrong order in your code, but you could also do

```
where year(rptdate) * 100) + month(rptdate) = @theMonth
```